# Unable to open Instruments after repeatedly seeing (RunLoop::Xcrun::TimeoutError) error

Tags: cucumber, calabash-ios

I've posted [this issue](https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/issues/368)

but believe I'm now running into a new one. We have automated tests that run every 15 minutes on a Jenkins server. While I'm still seeing the run_loop error listed in the link above, approximately once per hour I'm now seeing the following error in the console's output

```
    Xcrun timed out after 3.64 seconds executing

  xcrun instruments -s templates

  with a timeout of 30
   (RunLoop::Xcrun::TimeoutError)
```

When I see this and try to open Instruments, it says "Instruments cannot be opened at this time" and the only solution I've found so far is to reboot the server. This is problematic because there are several jobs running on this server at once and rebooting the machine every hour is not ideal. After rebooting the machine, Instruments is able to be opened and the tests run successfully for about another hour.

I can provide any further information necessary, just not sure where to go from here since I don't see much about this issue online.

Edit: My apologies, the missing information is
Xcode: 7.1.1
MacOS: 10.10.5
Calabash-Cucumber: 0.17.0

Comment: I am down voting because you have left out key pieces of information: Xcode, MacOS, and Calabash iOS versions. https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this as well on our Jenkins CI machine running El Cap and Xcode 7.2.  The CoreSimulator and instruments environment becomes unstable rather quickly.

Before running your tests, try:

```
# From Ruby
RunLoop::CoreSimulator.terminate_core_simulator_processes

# From the command line
$ bundle exec run-loop simctl manage-processes
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would solve our issue. We're running against a device, not a simulator. FWIW I did try it but to no avail.